# dereferencing when constructing dynamic object

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Why isn't the following used:

```
struct Foo
{
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    Foo &foo = *new Foo();
    foo.x = 7;
    std::cout << foo.x << std::endl;
    delete &foo;
}
```

After all, one must use references when possible, and with this approach, once we dereferenced initially, we never have to worry about forgetting it again. What are the downsides?

EDIT:

I know about `operator ->`, by forgetting i mean

```
int &n = *new int;
n = 7;
int *m = new int;
*m = 7; //here you can forget it
```

Comment: But you should delete the memory through `delete &foo;`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *forgetting*?

Comment: Use smart pointers, such as shared_ptr, which automatically delete their objects. In that case, your code will need no delete statements and it won't leak memory.

Comment: @NeilKirk all right, but you can also delete this way and it wont leak memory. This was about using the same syntax for dynamic objects.

Comment: I do agree this is one annoying part of C++, the fact that there are pointers and references (it is a little easier in C#, java since there are only references). I think it is just a peculiarity of the language which has evolved over so many years. Maybe just one of those things you have to live with?

Comment: @WayneUroda: C++ was initially just C with classes. There were no such things as references in C, and the `->` operator is from the C syntax to access members of a `struct` through a pointer.

Comment: @user315052 sorry, I don't understand your point - did I say something incorrect?

Comment: @WayneUroda: No, didn't mean to imply that you did.

Comment: I just meant to say, C++ is less symmetrical/homogeneous than say Java, because there is static allocation and dynamic allocation (vs Java with only dynamic), and in C++ you can pass objects by pointer or by reference (or by copy!), whereas Java again has no such divisions. I find when I write C++ I want to use references as much as possible (which I think is a good practice) BUT I find there are cases where you just can't avoid using pointers. I think it is just a fundamental part of C++ :) Not saying it's a Bad Thing!

Comment: @WayneUroda I'm happily living with it, I just like to still ask these silly questions, not because I think I found something noone thought of before, but because at first glance, it made sense to me, but I'm sure I'm wrong. I like to hear reasons from the more experienced, so if someone asks me later, I can answer myself. Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have a memory leak. You'd have to do something like this at the end of the function:

```
delete &foo;
```

This is a bad idea.

Comment: My experience is that I will start forgetting which variables are or are not dynamically allocated. It complicates things for me and for anyone reading the code.

Comment: Ok, so forgetting which variables to `delete` is a concern, yes.

Comment: A very big one, beside there is zero gain in dereferencing it, since you still will have to delete, and you wont forget to dereference it when its needed (I.E passing as argument to a function) because then it wont compile.

Comment: @AngelCastillo Ok, I see that, but is this the only reason? Not saying it isn't enough, I just want to be thorough.

Comment: In some situations you might need to change the assignment of foo, which isn't possible with references? That, and/or you will be in a very small minority (or the only person?!) who would write C++ this way? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in conjunction with a smart pointer.

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> p(new Foo);
Foo &foo = *p;
//...
```

Then, the memory will be properly deleted for you at the end of the scope.

Comment: Apart from the confusing syntax compared to simply allocating as `Foo foo;` I wonder if there is a compelling reason to allocate something in this way - for example, it is allocated on the heap and not the stack - could this make a difference (eg avoid stack overflows?) when used with very large objects?

Comment: The only reason I had thought of is if the instance needs to live beyond the scope of the reference. E.g., the pointer (or reference) is passed to a framework that manages the object instance. Your point about large objects overwhelming the stack is also a good reason to dynamically allocate over using a local instance.

Comment: If you want the memory to live longer than the scope of the reference, it will have to be `std::move`ed out of the `unique_ptr p`, right? I don't think this would be possible if all you have to work with is the reference to `*p` - I've only worked with auto_ptr and not yet C++11 so correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: @WayneUroda: Yes, it would have to be `std::move`ed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no visible downside of this approach. However, if one has to use reference with dynamic allocation, i.e. `T& t = *new T;`, then the design should be reconsidered.
Why? Because,

> "**References have to be initialized when declared**."

Which means, you cannot do `T& t;` and then allocate some memory to it.
Thus below statement:

```
T& t = *new T;  // (1) costly heap allocation (2) exception handling (3) need cleaning
```

becomes trivially inferior alternative to:

```
T t;  // (1) cheaper auto allocation (2) no exception (2) no need to clean
```

So even though you can dynamically allocate references, they are almost never needed.

Comment: Yes, the better use case is when a pointer is passed to a function. The function implementation can then use a reference and dereference the pointer argument to get a short-hand.

Comment: @user315052, but then one need to make sure that pointer is not null. Otherwise results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Re: "one must use references when possible"? Where does this (bad) advice come from?

```
Foo foo;
foo.x = 7;
std::cout << foo.x << std::endl;
```

No pointers, no references, no free store, no `delete`.

But when you do allocate from the free store, you get a pointer to the data object. Don't turn that into a reference unless you absolutely have to, and even then, don't do it.